# What is the fundamental concept behind a 2D Scrolling game camera?

Tags: c#, wpf, camera, 2d

A quick question- am I right to assume that a basic 2D camera for a parallax-style scrolling game relies fundamentally on a pseudo-pan effect of the camera following the player; but in actuality the game world environment is moving around a pretty much static game character, creating the effect of a parallax camera.

Or, is there indeed a deeper algorithm that caters for the scrolling of the virtual camera, with the character coordinates traversing the environment and the player view following it?

I initially presumed the former approach was the way forward, but when it comes to, say, two characters within the same scene moving irrespective of each other; the former approach faces issues, so I suspect the true approach to this logic is somewhat simple, but it eludes me right now.

Thanks for any help/links to appropriate resources.

P.S. I previously wrote a prototype camera functionality using WPF for the front-end, utilising the first approach I described. The results where basic, but worked. However I suspected that in a professional/indie title, the camera logic follows a more complex paradigm as opposed to a pseudo-pan, based on a moving environment.

```
     if (this.playerPositionXAxis >= this.cameraRightLimit)
        {
            // Camera shift/offset algorithm. RIGHT movement.
            double offset = Math.Abs(this.playerPositionXAxis - this.cameraRightLimit);
            this.MainCanvas.Margin = new Thickness(this.canvasMarginLeft -= offset, 0, -8, -10);

            this.cameraRightLimit += offset;
            this.cameraLeftLimit += offset;

            this.translateCamera = true;
        }

        if (this.playerPositionXAxis <= this.cameraLeftLimit)
        {
            // Camera shift/offset algorithm. LEFT movement.
            double offset = Math.Abs(this.playerPositionXAxis - this.cameraLeftLimit);
            this.MainCanvas.Margin = new Thickness(this.canvasMarginLeft += offset, 0, -8, -10);

            this.cameraLeftLimit -= offset;
            this.cameraRightLimit -= offset;

            this.translateCamera = true;

        }

        this.CameraLimitsTextBlock.Text = "Camera limit LEFT: " + this.cameraLeftLimit.ToString() +" Camera limit RIGHT: " + this.cameraRightLimit.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Forget any camera. This isn't 3d. The game picks the part of the background which is in view and this kind of moves. The sprite or picture of the character sits on top of this and might have his legs wiggling or some such. As I understand it, often there are effectively 3 tiles. The left, middle and right. These are animated and as one moves out of view they're logically switched and that one removed, another added.

Comment: Ahh I see, I suspected as much. Fundamentally I suppose it comes down to how you described it, perhaps I was overthinking the technicalities but what you put forward definitely affirms some of the initial ideas I had surrounding this question, thanks.